# Findind the derivative for an undefined function

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Suppose *$f$* and *$g$* are on a single graph.
let $$u(x) = f(x) g(x).$$

I need to find $u'(1) $ on the graph.

I understand finding derivatives with the product rule. 
However I don't know where to start when the graphic functions are not given.
Whats are the steps to solving this problem?[Graph of function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ytTS.png)

Comment: The slope of a straight line is the derivative of the corresponding function. See J.C. Santos' answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is clear from that graph that $f(1)=2$, that $f'(1)=2$, that $g(1)=1$, and that $g'(1)=-1$. That's all you need to compute $u'(1)$.

Comment: So _f_'(x) is the slope at the point. I completely forgot that, Thank you